# DataSource of Kendo element is undefined when used outside a function

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I noticed a strange behaviour of `Kendo MultiSelect` dataSource. 
When I call a function via some event of an element, like button click:

```
 function fillForm()
 {
  var ms = $("#selector").data('kendoMultiSelect');
  var ds = ms.dataSource.insert(....);
 };
```

When function fires the dataSource is defined. But when I want to call a function on page load:

```
var ms = $("#selector").data('kendoMultiSelect');
var ds = ms.dataSource.insert(....);
```

I see the error: `Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined`.

I would appreciate if someone can say what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The reason is that Document ready is directly called when the DOM is loaded but the kendo elements Source are set after that so if you wish to use the Data-source of any kendo elements at Document ready then you need to use **kendo.bind(document.body);** which I assume will bind all the relative kendo Elements to its sources. I am not completely sure of the flow, what I have explained is as per my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are trying to access the multiselect before it is initialized. Try to execute this code after you have initialized the widget.

If using the **MVC wrappers** then you should add the logic below the MVC wrapper code in a script block and in a document ready handler

e.g.

@(Html.Kendo().SomeWidget())

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          var ms = $("#selector").data('kendoMultiSelect');
          //your code goes here
      })
</script>
```

If using regular way of initialization through **JavaScript** either through $().kendoWidget or through kendo.bind() then you start trying to access it just below the widget code used for initialization.

```
    $("#ms").kendoMultiSelect({...}) // or kendo.bind('body')
    //widget is initialized 
    var ms = $("#ms").data('kendoMultiSelect');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if my multiSelect is in Razor view: @Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(...) how to reinitialize it? I tried to use $(#element).ready(function(){}) or load() but seems kendo widgets do not recognize them.